# Best practice for showing an error Alert

Tags: ios, error-handling, uialertview

I am having trouble displaying an Alert in case of an Error properly.

My idea is: Everytime I download data from my backend with an completion block, I present an Alert if an error occurs.

```
query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            createAlert(error)
            return

        } else if let objects = objects {
}
```

Since I got more than one call in a `ViewController` at the same time, it may happen to find myself having more than 2 or 3 Alerts presenting at the same time saying e.g. `"No Connection to the Internet"`.
It will constantly reload the Alert and it is a pain in terms of `UI`.

What is best practice to solve this issue?

My solution idea would be to put everything in a Singleton pattern and make sure no other other Alert is currently displayed.

Are there any better ways?

Comment: Show `createAlert`, please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a singleton pattern, you might prefer having an *optional **property*** (`var noConnectivityAlert`) in the class currently responsible for creating the alert.

 Instead of the `createAlert()` method you would have a `informUserAboutConnectivity()` method.

```
func informUserAboutConnectivity() {
    // If  noConnectivityAlert is nil
        // the method creates an alert and shows it.

    // If the property is NOT nil
        // do nothing (since the user is already informed).
}
```

When the internet connection would come back and then disappear again, some apps in the App Store would show an alert once again.
In that case, when the internet connection comes back you can directly set `noConnectivityAlert = nil` so that when the connection is lost, things will be handled nicely (a new alert will be created and shown).

By the way, in the iOS SDK, singletons are not used often. There are mostly used for providing a default and most common use case of a class (think of `UserDefaults`), or (of course) a shared manager/provider.

Comment: since there are more error than just 'connection failed' - I cannot use this, can I ?

Comment: If you have like <= 4 different kind of alerts, you may still use properties (one for each error category). If there are plenty of alert types to display concurrently you might **group** error messages (like displaying "Connection and database error" when the 2 types of error occurred at the same time). Also you should look at [Apple's recommandations](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/alerts/) concerning alerts in terms of design. The guidelines state: ***Minimize alerts** [...] Ensure that each alert offers critical information and useful choices*.

Comment: The point is minimising disruption and making it fluent for the user. In that regards, maybe you should state in the question the approximate number of alert types and give more details (can alerts be triggered simultaneously, or at a few seconds of interval, ...). It seems to me that your question must also be seen in terms of user experience and design aspects.